# Automapper - map all properties except the one that does not exist in destination

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

Using Automapper 3 (upgrading is not an option), I am wondering how can I map an entity (src) to destination where the property in destination does NOT exist in source?

Let's call the property in the destination some non mapped "temp" or "calculation" property. Of course when mapping, AM fails because the property in destination was not found in source.

```
CreateMap<SystemConfiguration, SystemConfigurationModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserRulesModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserRules));
```

In the "UserRulesModel", I have this temp property. I want AM to ignore it when mapping from the entity (DB) into the View Model (UserRulesModel)

UPDATE: UserRulesModel is a collection, as is UserRules.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure that when you create the map from `UserRules` to `UserRulesModel`:

```
CreateMap<UserRules, UserRulesModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Temp, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

**UPDATE**

Let's say `UserRules` is a collection of `UserRuleItem` objects and `UserRulesModel` is a collection of `UserRuleModelItem` objects.

If there is a property in `UserRuleModelItem` that is not present in `UserRuleItem`, you can configure AutoMapper to ignore that property using the syntax I posted originally:

```
CreateMap<UserRuleItem, UserRuleModelItem>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Temp, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The type of `dest` will be the type of object you are mapping to, which is `UserRuleModelItem` in this case.

Comment: I dont quite understand how that will work since I do want to map the object all but 1 property. Are you saying to add this after the previous line?

Comment: OK this does not quite work. The dest does not have the "Temp" property. It's the right hand side that has the property (UserRulesModel). Also the UserRulesModel is a collection.